# Revers expression to Polish Notation in Java

Tags: java, polish-notation

I want to make Reverse Polish Notation algorithm (from simple expression), but my code isn't working.
Can anyone explain me why?

**First of all I split a `String expression`to `array String[]` like this:**

```
String[] arraySymbols = expression.split(REGEX_SPLIT_EXPRESSION_BY_ONE_CHARACTER);
```

**Next step:**

```java
private final ArrayDeque<Expression> stackExpression = new ArrayDeque<>();
private final List<String> polishNotation = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    public List<String> interpret(String expression) {
        final String REGEX_SPLIT_EXPRESSION_BY_ONE_CHARACTER = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d|\\D)|(?<=\\d|\\D)(?=\\D)";

        String[] arraySymbols = expression.split(REGEX_SPLIT_EXPRESSION_BY_ONE_CHARACTER);

        for(String oneSymbolFormatString: arraySymbols) {
            char oneSymbolFormatChar = oneSymbolFormatString.charAt(0);
            Expression currentExpression;

            switch (oneSymbolFormatChar) {
                case '(':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionParenthesisOpen();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                case ')':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionParenthesisClosing();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                case '+':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionPlus();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionMinus();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionMultiply();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    currentExpression = new TerminalExpressionDivide();
                    comparePriority(currentExpression);
                    break;
                default:
                    polishNotation.add(oneSymbolFormatString);
            }
        }

        while (!stackExpression.isEmpty()) {
            polishNotation.add(stackExpression.pop().getName());
        }

        return polishNotation;
    }

private void comparePriority(Expression currentExpression) {
        if(stackExpression.isEmpty() | currentExpression.getName().equals(TypeExpression.PARENTHESIS_OPEN.getName())) {
            stackExpression.push(currentExpression);
        } else if(currentExpression.getName().equals(TypeExpression.PARENTHESIS_CLOSING.getName())) {
            while (true) {
                if(!stackExpression.getFirst().getName().equals(TypeExpression.PARENTHESIS_OPEN.getName())) {
                    polishNotation.add(stackExpression.pop().getName());
                } else {
                    stackExpression.pop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else if(stackExpression.getFirst().getPriority() >= currentExpression.getPriority()) {
            polishNotation.add(stackExpression.pop().getName());
            stackExpression.push(currentExpression);
        } else if(stackExpression.getFirst().getPriority() < currentExpression.getPriority()) {
            stackExpression.push(currentExpression);
        }
    }
```

**It contains a list of operations, their names, designations and priority:**

```java
public enum TypeExpression {
    NON_TERMINAL('\0',0),
    PARENTHESIS_OPEN('(',1),
    PARENTHESIS_CLOSING(')', 4),
    MINUS('-', 2),
    PLUS('+', 2),
    DIVIDE('/', 3),
    MULTIPLY('*', 3);

    private final char name;
    private final int priority;

    public String getName() {
        return String.valueOf(this.name);
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return this.priority;
    }

    TypeExpression(char name, int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

- For example. For this expression:

```java
(6+10-4)/(1+1*2)+1
```

my code return **correct** result:

```java
[6, 10, +, 4, -, 1, 1, 2, *, +, /, 1, +]
```

---

- But for this expression:

```java
(8+2*5)/(1+3*2-4)
```

my code return **incorrect** result:

```java
[8, 2, 5, *, +, 1, 3, 2, *, 4, -, +, /]
```

Should work **(correct)** is:

```java
8, 2, 5, *, +, 1, 3, 2, *, +, 4, -/
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: @AndyTurner, I don’t understand why the "reverse polish notation" algorithm works correctly in one case, and incorrectly in another. The sequence of steps in the algorithm is always the same. Maybe my algorithm is wrong? But if so, then he would incorrectly calculate the first expression.